# Best performance strategy for converting dates from MySQL format to Excel with PHP

Tags: php, performance, mysql, zend-framework

I'm still sort of new to PHP, MySQL (and Zend Framework). I need to convert dates to strings in MM/DD/YYYY format in order to interface with another system.

I have this function that I have pinpointed as the major performance killer of this particular script. When the result set is fairly small (40 or 50 rows), this runs quickly, less than a second. But when there are more records, say 4000, this function takes about 4 minutes. Not good.

What is the best strategy for cases like this to increase performance?

```
public function convertDatesToExcelFormat() {
    $sql = "Select fil_id,
        BIRTH_DATE,
        WILL_DATE,
        LAST_CODICIL_DATE,
        TRUST_DATE,
        POA_DATE
        FROM adds";
    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
    foreach ($result as $rowset => $row) {
        foreach ($row as &$val) {
            if (strpos($val, ':')) {
                $val = preg_replace('/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/', '' , $val);
                $val = preg_replace('/-/', '/', $val);
                $val = substr($val, -6, 5) . '/' . substr($val, 0, 4);
            }
        }
        $data = array(
                'BIRTH_DATE'        => $row['BIRTH_DATE'],
                'WILL_DATE'         => $row['WILL_DATE'],
                'LAST_CODICIL_DATE' => $row['LAST_CODICIL_DATE'],
                'TRUST_DATE'        => $row['TRUST_DATE'],
                'POA_DATE'          => $row['POA_DATE'],
        );
        $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('fil_id = ?', $row['fil_id']);
        $this->update($data, $where);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Let the database do it: [MySQL: date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). This regex is the performance killer. And why the second loop? Does not make sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for the MySQL link. Are you sure the second loop doesn't make sense? This may be a peculiarity of Zend Framework, but this is how I've had to extract the values. How would you rewrite the loop?

Comment: You don't need that loop at all when you let the database do the formatting.

Comment: I just want to point out that in Excel, a date is just a number with a special format.  If you were to export this into Excel it would look at that data in those cells as text making it useless for things like sorting or pivot tables.

Comment: @Falcon - right, but if the database wasn't doing it (as is the case in the code above), then the nested loop would be necessary, right?

Comment: @maple_shaft that's a good point, but another script on another server (which I don't have access to) specifically requires this be a string to do the upload. Someone over there thought it would be 'easier' for for us to be able to upload an excel file rather than a CSV, but they made it so that all of the fields require a text data type (string).

Answer (score 0):

php has a very useful function called date_format which takes the form of

```
$newDateVar = date_format('d-M-Y', $inputDateVar);
```

The string 'd-M-Y' above can be cast in various formats. Have a look on the php site which gives a full breakdown of the formats available
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php